# Enable communication between React Web Application and Electron Desktop Application (Exe)?

Tags: reactjs, electron

My React web application opens up the electron app through the custom url scheme - but is there a way for me to enable communication between the desktop app and the web app? I need to send specific data to the electron app (e.g. chosen process ids of a particular employee). The electron app itself is a screen-recording app, that has a logger at its backend - I'm hoping to save the data to a specific database, and re-retrieve it in the web-application when needed.
Currently, the web application only opens the electron app using the custom url scheme (Windows Registry) - is there a way to send params through it? I'm super stuck.

I'm not sure where to start.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You can open the app with custome schema like: your-app://?param1=value1&param2=value2 by handle 'open-url' event in main process